# C#, ASP.NET MVC IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath has wrong path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-10

I have an ASP.NET MVC website written in C# that when run from Visual Studio has a webpage (Razor view) that prints the value of `IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath`. This project is stored in `c:\dev\projects\site_A`, the webpage renders `c:\dev\projects\site_A\wwwroot`.

I publish this website to directory `d:\www\qa`, create a new website in IIS and point it to the published directory (`d:\www\qa`).

When I use the "Browse Website" link from within IIS, the same webpage displays the value for `IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath` as being:

```
c:\dev\projects\site_A\wwwroot
```

But from IIS it should render:

```
d:\www\qa\wwwroot
```

There are no symbolink links involved.

How can this happen?

Comment: What are the site bindings you set on IIS and what is the URL you use in browser? Those can decide if you are viewing the correct web page, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: I have test the IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath. It show different path when application run on VS and IIS. So when you access it, did you clear cache in browser? Can you post the code so that I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @LexLi The IIS site is running on port 80, and has it's own virtual domain. The site run from Visual Studio is using IIS Express and the port number is well into the thousands. I'm definitely using the correct URL.

Comment: @BruceZhang I tried dumping cache, recycled Application Pool, and restarted the site. The codebase is much too large to share, and making a sample will be time consuming. The short version is that I use dependency injection to get an instance of IWebHostEnvironment, and then pass IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath into my View.

Comment: I also used dependency injection to get an instance and pass webrootpath into view. It works well and shows the correct path. So it is difficult to reproduce the issue without your code or sample. Try to create an empty application and test IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath again. Maybe other code affect the webRootPath in your project.

Comment: `private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _web;
        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,IWebHostEnvironment webhost)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _web = webhost;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["a"] = _web.WebRootPath;
            return View();
        }`  Here is the code that I test, you can use it in an empty application.